# Is it safe/okay to add paths to tsconfig.json file of npm packages?

Tags: angular, typescript, node-modules, tsconfig

Hey guys so I am upgrading an angular package from v5 to v8 and all seems well but when I install the package, I get a static injector error in my console.

[image]
But when I add paths to the tsconfig of my project, the error goes away.

```
 "paths": {
  "@angular/common": ["node_modules/@angular/common"],
}
```

Is there a way to prevent that? like adding the paths to the main package and not each individual projects

Comment: How did you arrive at this solution? Have you found the root cause? Usually, such an error indicates problems with imports and looking at the fix I would bet you have another `angular` as a subdependency, so I would suggest wipe and reinstall `node_modules` and ensure there is no dependencies that contain old versions of angular inside (`npm ls @angular/common`).

Comment: I found the solution online and it worked but my main question is why is the npm i 'my-package-name' causing that error? not until i add the paths config to the project importing it before it works. Okay so I should do a wipe of the nodemodules in the package yeah? I really have not found the root cause actually

Comment: If your 'my-package-name' package has listed angular as a dependency it can happen you will have a few angulars in the bundle and it causes a mess. It might work for a while and shows up now because now its versions incompatible. If it is your own package make sure it follow the rule described in the [official doc](https://angular.io/guide/creating-libraries#use-typescript-path-mapping-for-peer-dependencies)

Comment: okay thanks man. I already added the path as instructed in the documentation. Will update and give feedback

Comment: no difference. same error

Comment: So could you add the result of `npm ls @angular/common` command to your question?

Comment: `@angular/common@8.2.14`  is what I get when I ran `npm ls @angular/common`